# Преобразование json-ответа

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, pandas

Пытаюсь заниматься парсингом, с сайта получил json-ответ, пытаюсь работать над ним библиотекой pandas.

```
import json
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://1xstavka.ru/results/getmain'
params = {'showAll': 'true', 'date': '2020-03-09'}
headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

r = response.json() 
basket = r['results'][1]['Elems']                   
for i in basket:
    for j in i['Elems']:
        with open('response.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            json.dump(j, file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)

df = pd.read_json('response.json')
print(df)
```

Выдает почему то в ответ, только последний результат из json. Как получить полную таблицу и как можно получить только определенные столбцы?

Comment: Открытие файла в режиме 'w' стирает все предыдущее содержимое файла. Нужно один раз открыть файл до цикла, записать в него все что вы хотели записать, закрыть файл.

Comment: А как его открыть до цикла, если нужна информация сохраняется в переменной после цикла?

Comment: 1 - если действительно нужен файл, то нужно вынести with наружу циклов. 2 - в файле у вас будет формироваться невалидный json - скорее всего нужно формировать список из элементов, потом уже передавать их в файл.

Answer (score 0):

Создал список перед началом цикла, результат цикла добавил в список.

```
r = response.json() 
score =[]
basket = r['results'][1]['Elems']                   
for i in basket:
   for j in i['Elems']:
       score.append(j)


with open('response.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(score, file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)

df = pd.read_json('response.json')
print(df)
```